# Configure Nokogiri to avoid empty XML::Text entries?

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm currently using Ruby with Nokogiri and Nori. I read XML documents using:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('file.xml')) { |config| config.strict }
```

The XML document has indentations to make it more readable, but Nokogiri takes these indentations and turns them into Nokogiri::XML::Text objects, which I don't want.

For example, consider this simple XML document:

```
<root>
  <level1>value</level1>
</root>
```

Nokogiri produces the following out of it:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x12a7564 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x12a6fb0 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x12a6ca4 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x12a6b14 name="level1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x12a640c "value">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x12a5e80 "\n">]>]>
```

Instead, what I'd like to get is:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x12a7564 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x12a6fb0 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x12a6b14 name="level1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x12a640c "value">]>]>]>
```

Notice that Nokogiri::XML::Text entries capturing the indentations (e.g. `#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x12a6ca4 "\n  ">`) are not present in my manually-edited example.

These unwanted entries cause problems later when trying to iterate over fields and other objects (e.g. checking attributes, etc).

Is there a way to configure `Nokogiri` to *avoid* adding these unwanted indentation-based entries and only those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this resolves your problem: you might simply use the `noblanks` option:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('file.xml')) { |config| config.strict }
xml2 = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('file.xml')) { |config| config.strict.noblanks }
```

`xml` will give you:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3ff585c84550 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff585c84050 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff586427ca8 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff586427aa0 name="level1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff5864275b4 "value">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff58642708c "\n">]>]>
```

and `xml2` will be:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3ff58640fdb0 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff58640f964 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff58640f004 name="level1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff58640eb2c "value">]>]>]>
```